# Transform a listbox to textbox

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to transform a listbox to textbox when I'm clicking a checkbox.
To explain, i have a listbox that contains addresses and if an address does't belong in the list someone can click to a checkbox called 'another address';so he can put another address.Thanx for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

1. Place the `ListBox` and the `TextBox` controls on top of each other in your form layout.
2. Set the `textBox.Visibility = false` by default (on form load).
3. When `checkbox.OnClick` set `listBox.Visible = !checkbox.Checked` and `textBox.Visible = checkbox.Checked`.